# preload="none" not working for video.js YouTube plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js, youtube-iframe-api

Inside React component trying to use video.js [Youtube plugin](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube) with `preload="none"` but it still downloads posters for the video on page load.

Preferred behaviour is to show black screen until user clicks the 'play' button.

Any ideas why that could happen?

```
<video 
  id="11179-0" 
  className="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
  controls 
  preload="none" 
  data-setup={ "preload": "none",
               "techOrder": ["youtube"],
               "sources": [{"type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://youtu.be/d88APYIGkjk"}] 
             }>
</video>
```

Comment: There are no preload option in video.js https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#Parameters where did you find this option?

Comment: well, I read "..It supports every regular Video.js options...' here https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube#options and then found the option here https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/options.md#preload

Comment: is there any way to stop preloading for youtube in this case?

Comment: You can try to ask using github issues for youtube plugin.

Comment: Done. Thanks.  - https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/issues/363